# CKeditor adding class to img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I am trying to add a class to any inserted img tag in CKeditor. I have tried various ways but can't seem to figure out how the setting of this plugin works. Whilst there are tonnes of documents, it only mentions that a code needs to be added, but not where it should be added, there are loads of files.

I tried adding it to the bottom on config.js

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2014, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
    // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Set the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    // Simplify the dialog windows.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
    config.extraPlugins = 'confighelper';   

    config.stylesSet = 'my_styles';

};

CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles', [

    { name: 'Custom Image', element: 'img', attributes: { 'class': 'myClass' }}
]);
```

That didn't work

So I tried adding it to the actual html page

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles', [

    { name: 'Custom Image', element: 'img', attributes: { 'class': 'myClass' }}
]);
</script>
```

That didn't work either

Reading their docs I can't make any sense of it http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_styles

How does one add a class to any img tags added through the editor?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using CKEDITOR, but the problem could be, that the stylesSet is not declared on CKEDITOR call, since its defined later. 
Try moving `CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add` prior to editorConfig.

Alternatively put your styles into the first code block:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

   ...
   ...

   config.stylesSet = [
      { name: 'Custom Image', element: 'img', attributes: { 'class': 'myClass' }}
   ];

};
</script>
```

There are also some more Docs about the usage http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-stylesSet