# How to automatically add a class to images in the body field in CKeditor

Tags: image, drupal-7, ckeditor

I would like the ability to add a class to images which are added to the body field in Drupal.

I want to keep things as simple as possible for our users, whereby they don't have to add classes etc.  Ideally they would just click on the image button in the toolbar, paste the URL or upload an image and set align either left or right:
[Image properties for adding images in CKeditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIExq.jpg)

I've tried several options, including: [CKEditor adding class to img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181100/ckeditor-adding-class-to-img-tag?rq=1) but I cannot get anything to work.

The path to CKEditor is to the CDN //cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.4/full-all

I'd like to us my own SCSS to make the images float left or right at desktop, and be centered for the small breakpoint.

The text format is 'filtered HTML'.

Is there any way I can get this to work?

Many Thanks

**Update**

Because I'm using the CKEditor CDN, I've added the following to my local 'ckeditor.config.js' file

```
config.extraPlugins = 'image, dialog, dialogui';

// Enable local "imagetoolbar" plugin from /myplugins/imagetoolbar/ folder.
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'image', '/plugins/image/' 'plugin.js' );
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'dialog', '/plugins/dialog/' 'plugin.js' );
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'dialogui', '/plugins/dialog/' 'plugin.js' );

// extraPlugins needs to be set too.
CKEDITOR.replace( 'news', {
extraPlugins: 'image, dialog, dialogui'
} );
```

The example I copied this from has 'news' as the CKEDITOR.replace, which I'm sure is wrong, what should this be? https://www.pluginsforckeditor.com/Tutorials/149/How-to-add-a-plugin-to-CKEditor/en/n149.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the image plugin in order to have the class of the image already entered. So users just have to paste URL or upload an image.

[image: this is the code you have to modify]

Fill the default field with what you want.

I hope to help you.

Comment: You can create a new local plugin identical to the image plugin with the changes I have told you ?

Comment: @dakaydo I've created the plugin and filled the default with my css class m-image.  Image has two dependencies, dialog and dialogui, all three are enabled in Editor appearance in Drupal.  Your screengrab appears in my image.js file, which is located: sites > all > modules > ckeditor > plugins > image > dialogs >image.js

Comment: I really wish this was straight forward, but it's a flippin' complicated nightmare!! Still can't get it to work, what am I doing wrong? I get the feeling the local plugins are not being initialised.

Comment: Hey @ snarf1974, comme vous l'avez dit, il faut charger les plugins comme celui-ci :                                                                                                          
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'abbr'
} );

Comment: I have added plugins like this, but it's still not working!

Comment: You add the plugin in the toolbar too ?

Comment: did you succeed ?

Comment: No, it's unbelievably frustrating!!

Comment: `Drupal.settings.cke_toolbar_DrupalBasic = [ [ 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList','BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Image', 'image', ] ];`

Comment: I've added 'image' to the toolbar, but still nothing.  Not sure if it's even picking up anything from ckeditor.config.js

Comment: Be careful to have changed the name of the plugin and of the button. Try to have more difference between your names

Comment: Right, the image plugin that is included with ckeditor CDN is working fine, but it's still not adding a class to the image. I've added `config.extraPlugins = 'image';` to my local ckeditor.config.js file and also in advanced options Custom JavaScript configuration in Drupal along with `config.justifyClasses = [ 'rteleft', 'rtecenter', 'rteright', 'rtejustify' ];`.  I've also added my css class 'default': 'm-test' in image.js. I cannot believe how unbelievably difficult it is just to achieve something which on the face of it should be so simple.

Comment: Sorry for the long winded comments ,but I need to get up to a reputation of 20 in order to use the chat facility.

Comment: Is the button for the new plugin visible? If it's not the case, verifies that you have correctly replace the names (for example name of the button, the name of the file, ...).To facilitate the thing used a completely different name from the basic one.

Comment: Yes, the button is visible. It's just the 'image' button which comes with CKeditor CDN. Think I just need to have a break away from this for a couple of days, as I'm tempted to throw my computer out of the window!